# Achieve stricter return typing on function with complicated parameter typing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have an object of type

```
type CompoundType = (IType1 | IType2)[] | (IType3 | IType4)[];
```

Where `IType1, IType2, IType3, IType4, ... , ITypeN extend (A | B)`

I wish to write a genericized function to perform an operation on each item of the `CompoundType` object, and cast the return type to be strictly `SomeOperation<IType1 | IType2 | IType3 | IType4>[]`

What I have already:

```
const wrapWithOperation = (items: (A | B)[]): SomeOperation<A | B>[] => {
   // implementation
}
```

Unfortunately, the return type of `wrapWithOperation(obj as CompoundType)` isn't `SomeOperation<IType1 | IType2 | IType3 | IType4>[]`, it's `SomeOperation<IType1 | IType2 | IType3 | ... | ITypeN>[]`. I'm pretty sure this can be accomplished by generics in the function pointer type definition, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I've understood your setup fully, but I think I get the issue.  These are the dummy types that I'm working with.

```
type IType1 = {1: string}
type IType2 = {2: string}
type IType3 = {3: string}
type IType4 = {4: string}

type CompoundType = (IType1 | IType2)[] | (IType3 | IType4)[];

type SomeOperation<T> = {
    didSomething: T;
}
```

We have a function that acts on an array.  Instead of passing it an array where we know the element type beforehand, we have an array which can be one of two types.  Those types themselves: `IType1 | IType2` and `IType3 | IType4` are unions of other types, but that's not the breakdown point.

```
const wrapWithOperation = <T>(items: T[]): SomeOperation<T>[] => {
   return items.map( i => ({didSomething: i}));
}

declare const x: CompoundType;

const res = wrapWithOperation(x); // error here
```

Using a generic `T` to represent each element of the array seems like it would work but it actually gives an error.  Typescript says that `CompoundType` is not assignable to `CompoundType` which is a real "huh?" unless you understand step by step what typescript is doing.

If you want to assign `T` to `A | B`, typescript sees if it `extends A` and sees if it `extends B` and if either is true then it's ok.  But `A | B` does not extend `A` or extend `B` so by this strange logic, `A | B` does not extend `A | B`.

So how do we fix this?

We instead assign the generic `T` to the whole array.  When we return `SomeOperation` we need to know the type of each element of the array `T`, so we use `infer` to work backwards.

```
const wrapWithOperation = <T extends any[]>(items: T): SomeOperation<T extends (infer X)[] ? X : never>[] => {
   return items.map( i => ({didSomething: i}));
}
```

Now we get a result with the desired type `SomeOperation<IType1 | IType2 | IType3 | IType4>[]`